# How to achieve a check box or category oriented photo gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not sure the best way to word this question, hence why Google left me hanging.

Essentially I want to create a photo gallery that has (for example) 30 pictures and of those 30 pictures, there are 3 different categories they can be put into.

I want the user to be able to click a check box to either show or hide the different categories (and subsequent pictures) or view them all.

For example, there would be 4 check boxes to the left of a photo gallery. The top box would be ALL, then Category 1, Category 2, Category 3. As you clicked each box, only those "types" of images would appear.

Any hints on code (or even the type of code I should be looking for, i.e. CSS, Javascript, jQuery) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How do you plan on delivering the images? Are they all populated on page load, and then hidden, and when you click the checkboxes you want to to fade them in? or are you driving this site with ajax, and you plan on sending a query to the server to send back the images you want. Also, how will you store the relationship between teh checkbox and the image? `<img rel="category1 category2" src="whatever.ext" />` where the category's are held in the rel attribute of the image, and we split the rel and check if the checkbox value is in the array of the image rel?

Comment: You have a whole host of options for doing this. HTML, CSS, JQUERY and probably PHP would be my choice.  Ohgodwhy above has some good ideas.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I would ideally like them to all be populated on page load. They would be thumbnails that of course would enlarge upon click.

The relationship would be just as you said.

Comment: @SubstanceD I would definitely prefer sticking to HTML/CSS/Javascript, in which I know them much better than say PHP/jQuery (although I can do a little in both languages).

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/kVCm4/](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/xdmd2/) -- Here you go.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much @Ohgodwhy!! I can't tell you how much I appreciate it! That is perfect.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I seem to be having trouble with what appears to be my jQuery not running right. When I preview the page, the radios show up but no pictures (whether or not I click on the buttons)

Comment: Here is the top portion of my code:
`code`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.chkbox-container :radio').on('change', function(){
  var me = $(this);
  $.each($('.img-container img'), function(i,v){
    var theCats = $(v).attr('rel');
    theCats = theCats.split(' ');
    if($.inArray(me.val(), theCats)){
      $(v).show();
    }else{
      $(v).hide();
    }
      
  });        
});
</script>
`code`

Comment: @Jamez14 Please take the relevant code and place it into a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @Ohgodwhy here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamez14/tmvq3/) and also the entire code is here on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rmPm9Rid). My jsFiddle runs fine, therefore I believe my issue is somewhere in the head of my code which you can find via Pastebin. Once again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @jamez14 This all looks good, your pastebin works fine copied directly to my site (replaced with images on my hDD, of course). Have you verified that the image path's are correct, and, that the jQuery library is at the correct path? I would perform a `console.log('the change')` within the `.on('change'` function I built for you. If it's not firing, then the jQuery library isn't working. If you have other libraries you're using with jQuery, you may need to protect your jquery function. `(function($){$(function(){ //the script }); })(jQuery);`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Protecting my jQuery function did the trick! I really appreciate you helping me out with this!!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS ->

```
.chkbox-container{
  float:left;
  width:95px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;    
}
.img-container{
  float:left;
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;    
}
img{
  display:inline-block;
  width:90px;
  height:75px;
  padding:2px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:none;    
}
```

The JQuery ->

```
$('.chkbox-container :radio').on('change', function(){
  var me = $(this);
  $.each($('.img-container img'), function(i,v){
    var theCats = $(v).attr('rel');
    theCats = theCats.split(' ');
    if($.inArray(me.val(), theCats)){
      $(v).show();
    }else{
      $(v).hide();
    }

  });        
});
```

The HTML ->

```
<div class="chkbox-container">
  <input type="radio" name="catfilter[]" value="all" checked="checked"/> All<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="catfilter[]" value="category1" /> Category 1<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="catfilter[]" value="category2" /> Category 2<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="catfilter[]"value="category3" /> Category 3<br/>
</div>
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="path.to/the/image/ext" rel="category1" />
  <img src="path.to/the/image/ext" rel="category2" />
  <img src="path.to/the/image/ext" rel="category3" />
</div>
```

[Working jsFiddle for anyone that finds it useful.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/xdmd2/)